# Can I compute a change of measure? If so, how?

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

I have a single shock that can be expressed as:

$S=\mu_A+ \sigma_A \varepsilon^A_t \\$ 
  or as
$S=\mu_B+ \sigma_B \varepsilon^B_t$
 Where  $\varepsilon^A_t,\varepsilon^B_t \sim \mathcal{N}(0,1) \quad i.i.d.$

I feel that because they are the same shock, there should be a change of measure that expresses what B sees from A's perspective. Clearly:

$\varepsilon^B_t= \frac{\mu_A-\mu_B}{\sigma_B}+\frac{\sigma_A}{\sigma_B}\varepsilon^A_t$

Is it possible to I find something like $\eta$ such that:
$E_B[S]=E_A[\eta S]$

Thank you!